# Label Scroll effect

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, label

Im using a Label where text input from a text box is shown in that label. Now, I whant to make the label text scroll. I´ve looked around through the internet and I tried to write this into the code inside of the label:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int Scroll;
    string strString = "This is scrollable text...This is scrollable text...This is scrollable text";

    Scroll = Scroll + 1;
    int iLmt = strString.Length - Scroll;
    if (iLmt < 20)
    {
        Scroll = 0;
    }
    string str = strString.Substring(Scroll, 20);
    label1.Text = str;
}
```

Does anybody see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: if you have this within a label, it should only be shifted once. Use a timer to periodically call the scroll

Comment: Please `define "what you want" and "what's not working"`

Comment: the text thats showig on the label should scroll once on the screen, the scrolling effect should go from left to right and it should be readable. I also have a textbox and a button on my form. The text box is for writting text in it and the button should be pressed when done. After pressing the button the text that the user wrote should be displayed (and scrolled) inside of the label.

Answer (score 6):

//much easier:

```
private void timer2scroll_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  label10Info.Text = label10Info.Text.Substring(1, label10Info.Text.Length - 1) + label10Info.Text.Substring(0,1);
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare the Scroll variable outside of you function call, it is reset every time you click it.

Here it the code with a timer on the form load to auto scroll the text:

```
private Timer tmr;
private int scrll { get; set; }

void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(this.TimerTick);
    tmr.Interval = 200;
    tmr.Start();
}

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScrollLabel();
}

private void ScrollLabel()
{
    string strString = "This is scrollable text...This is scrollable text...This is scrollable text";

    scrll = scrll + 1;
    int iLmt = strString.Length - scrll;
    if (iLmt < 20)
    {
        scrll = 0;
    }
    string str = strString.Substring(scrll, 20);
    label1.Text = str;
}

private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScrollLabel();
}
```

Comment: Yes i got that, but i want the text to scroll automatically, now i have to tap on the text to scroll, any ideas on how that can be done?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using my library.

> **WinForm Animation Library [.Net3.5+]**
>
> A simple library for animating controls/values in .Net WinForm (.Net
>   3.5 and later). Key frame (Path) based and fully customizable.

https://falahati.github.io/WinFormAnimation/

```
    var textToScroll = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.";
    var durationOfAnimation = 5000ul;
    var maxLabelChars = 20;
    var label = label1;

    new Animator(new Path(0, 100, durationOfAnimation))
    {
        Repeat = true,
        ReverseRepeat = true
    }.Play(
        new SafeInvoker<float>(f =>
        {
            label.Text =
                textToScroll.Substring(
                    (int) Math.Max(Math.Ceiling((textToScroll.Length - maxLabelChars)/100f * f) - 1, 0),
                    maxLabelChars);
        }, label));
```

Comment: kindly help me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251468/how-to-stop-animation-in-c-sharp-using-winformanimation/57251745?noredirect=1#comment101005971_57251745

Comment: This did not work me. Any help appreciated.