# How to Stop Animation in C# using WinFormAnimation?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I have a scrolling text, when the Load button is pressed, the animation starts, however it does not stop when Stop button is pressed, it keeps on scrolling.

1. I have created button name "Load."
2. When Load is pressed, text starts scrolling.
3. In the Load button the name of button is changed to "Stop."

There is only 1 button "Load". The name of the button changes to Stop. when Load button is pressed, so the second time user presses the same button, it goes into stop button code to stop the animation.

4. It goes into "Stop." button code that is mf.button1.Text == "Stop." where Animator.Stop(); is used to stop the animation, the animation does not stop.
5. However when the animator.stop(); is used right after safe invoker in load code, it does stops there.
6. I want the user to stop the scrolling text.

```
using WinFormAnimation;
private void ScrollLabel()
{ 
            string textToScroll = sample;
            var durationOfAnimation = 250000ul;
            var maxLabelChars = 115;
            var label = mf.label16;
            var winform = new WinFormAnimation.Path(0, 100, durationOfAnimation);
            var animator = new Animator(winform);

            try
            {
                if (mf.button1.Text == "Load.")
                {
                    animator.Play(
                    new SafeInvoker<float>(f =>
                    {
                        label.Text =
                            textToScroll.Substring(
                                (int)Math.Max(Math.Ceiling((textToScroll.Length - maxLabelChars) / 100f * f) - 1, 0),
                                maxLabelChars);
                    }, label));
                    mf.button1.Text = "Stop."
                }

                    if (mf.button1.Text == "Stop.")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Animator Stop!");
                        animator.Stop();
                    }

            }
            catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ex) { ex.Message.ToString(); }
        }
    }
```

I expect the scroll to be stopped when the Stop Button is pressed and Start when Load Button is pressed.

Library used: https://falahati.github.io/WinFormAnimation/

Comment: You create a new Animator every time you enter this code. So the animator you are trying to stop, is not the one that you started.

Comment: I have more than 1 scrolling texts, when I start the second one, it starts on the top of this one. I want this one to stop so I start another scrolling text. 

how do I stop the existing animator?

Comment: You can't stop if if you dont keep a reference to it. See my answer.

Comment: Is this supposed to work as a marquee?

Comment: I put this code in a seperate class. I accessed the Main Interface instance from that class to access labels for setting scroll text. I did this so I could seperate the whole code from the main interface but this was the issue. I put back the entire code back to main form, now it is working.

Comment: I was creating class object in the main form to go to my method and set fields to my main form by taking the same instance of the mainform. For example. Object o1 = new Object(), o1.ScrollText(). MainForm.Label1.Text.  when called back from mainform the code would not stop animation.

Comment: To Understand this you will have to see my entire code working, which where I may have been doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Move the animator outside `ScrollLabel`.

```
using WinFormAnimation;

private Path winform = null;
private Animator animator = null;

private void InitAnimator()
{
    var durationOfAnimation = 250000ul;
    winform = new Path(0, 100, durationOfAnimation);
    animator = new Animator(winform);
}

private void ScrollLabel()
{ 
    string textToScroll = sample;
    var maxLabelChars = 115;
    var label = mf.label16;
    if (winform == null)
    {
        InitAnimator();
    }        
    try
    {
        if (mf.button1.Text == "Load.")
        {
            animator.Play(
                    new SafeInvoker<float>(f =>
                    {
                        label.Text =
                            textToScroll.Substring(
                                (int)Math.Max(Math.Ceiling((textToScroll.Length - maxLabelChars) / 100f * f) - 1, 0),
                                maxLabelChars);
                    }, label));
            mf.button1.Text = "Stop."
        }
        else if (mf.button1.Text == "Stop.")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Animator Stop!");
            animator.Stop();
        }

    }
    catch (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException ex) 
    { 
        ex.Message.ToString(); // This does absolutely nothing
    }
}
```

This would be a bare minimum solution. You should keep a state instead of relying on checking button texts. And you should do something sensible with the exception.

Comment: CS0118 'WinFormAnimation' is a namespace but is used like a type 

Yes. I do not get any exception. something to be fixed here.

Comment: I don't know WinformAnimation and since you prefixed it to `Path`, I just assumed. I have fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: still the animator does not stop. There is one more problem to my code. 
When Load button is pressed, animation starts, Button name changes to stop and then the stop button load is executed and animation is stopped without pressing stop button. 

if i put return after button text is changed to stop, the animation does not stop and the button name also changes to stop. Next time when I press "Stop." again. the animator does not stop.

Comment: should I make the winform and animator both to null in "Stop" button code?

Comment: Looking at your/my code again there is something very wrong. The animation ought to stop right away, since we already set the Text to "Stop.". I will look at the code again and try to fix it.

Comment: I have changed the condition to else if button1.text == "Stop." but still next time the stop button is pressed the animation does not stop. 
I have tried making winform and animator null in the stop button code but nothing happens, there is something to do with safe invoker i guess.

Comment: I added the else as well, but I get no "animation". I'm not certain what is is you want to achieve anyway. I rest my case, I don't have the time to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @PalleDue example and it seems to work alright. So there should be some sort of problem with your reference to the animator instance.

The right way to do this if you have multiple scrolling labels and multiple buttons is to use a `UserControl` and write your code regarding all this there. And then use that in your form. And don't change the content of the `UserControl` directly from the form. The whole idea of creating a new `UserControl` is to encapsulate the logic.

In any case, the least you can do to solve the problem is to use the `Control.Tag` property of one of the controls to store additional information; in this case the `Animator` instance. Following is a simple example that I tested and works alright (with one label and one button):

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get reference to the button and the label
    var label = label1;
    var button = button1;

    // Get a reference to the animator responsible for this label
    var animator = label.Tag as Animator;

    try
    {
        if (animator?.CurrentStatus == AnimatorStatus.Playing)
        {
            // If playing; stop
            button.Text = @"Play";
            animator.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            // Load the text and calculate the size of the label in chars as well as expected rows
            string textToScroll = @"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";
            var labelWidthInChars = (int)(label.Width / label.CreateGraphics().MeasureString("A", label.Font).Width);
            var labelRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)textToScroll.Length / labelWidthInChars);

            // Create a new animator and set it to animate from (0) to the (number of rows - 1) 
            // in 10 seconds with 10fps maximum callback frequency
            label.Tag = animator = new Animator(new Path(0, labelRows - 1, 10000), FPSLimiterKnownValues.LimitTen);

            button.Text = @"Stop";
            animator.Play(
                new SafeInvoker<float>(f =>
                    {
                        label.Text = textToScroll.Substring(labelWidthInChars * (int)Math.Floor(f));
                    },
                    label));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

P.S.: When working with open source projects; if there is an issue tracker for the project; you should probably post your problem there. This will notify the developer of the project (unlike StackOverflow) and therefore probably results in your problem getting solved faster.

https://github.com/falahati/WinFormAnimation/issues